# How to structure this IF condition in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a MySQL trigger. I have two tables that look like this:

[image: tables]

When a customer makes a purchase a new record is added to each table. I have added column ‘sku_copy’ to Table B, so it does not get populated when a new record is created.

When a new record is created, I want my trigger to copy the ‘sku’  field in Table A to the ‘sku_copy’ field in Table B. However, the problem I am having is how to structure the following condition in the trigger.

IF: ‘order_id’ in Table A matches ‘order_id’ in Table B. THEN: copy ‘sku’ from that Table A record to the record in Table B with the matching ‘order_id’. The data should be added to Table B ‘sku_copy'.

ELSE: don’t do anything.

Can someone show me how to write this into my trigger?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Are you sure that you *want* to make a copy like this? Having the same data in two places can be problematic (for example, if you update one, you have to be sure to update the other). It might be simpler just to do a JOIN whenever you need to select the SKU that goes with a given order #.

Comment: Hi Russell - thanks for responding. I need to have 'sku' in Table B in order for it to be useable by another application. This is a sales record so the only update will be a delete when it's no longer needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this but why do u think of using trigger for this ?

```
 DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
        AFTER INSERT ON tableA
        FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        INSERT INTO tableB
        SET sku_copy = OLD.sku,
             order_id = OLD.order_id,
            order = OLD.order;

    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks - I want to use a trigger to get the sku into Table B because I would need to find someone to hack a third party program to accomplish what this trigger will do. Also my current knowledge level supports this solution better that altering the code in the other program.

Comment: I'm getting the this error message when I run the trigger: #1363 - There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger

Comment: Moderators: please don't delete my new posts here. I need an answer to this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I want to post the trigger that was constructed with examples offered here and on another forum. Thanks to everyone who helped with this.

```
DELIMITER $$

   CREATE TRIGGER sku_AfterInsert
     AFTER INSERT ON uau3h_virtuemart_order_items
     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

     UPDATE uau3h_virtuemart_orders
     SET order_item_sku_copy = NEW.order_item_sku
     WHERE virtuemart_order_id = NEW.virtuemart_order_id;
  END$$;

DELIMITER ;
```